# postgres error 42803 with subquery and group by

Tags: postgresql, subquery

Hi all postgres developer,

below code can run success

```
select p.* from
    (select p.*, count(distinct p1.id) n from TMB p
        left join TMB p1 on p.id = p1.pid
        left join TUR u on p.id = any(u.jks)
        group by p.id) p
    join TUR u on u.id = p.uid
```

but, below code with error message
`[42803] ERROR: column "p.xxxx" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

```
select p.* from
    (select p.*, count(distinct p1.id) n from (select * from TMB) p
        left join TMB p1 on p.id = p1.pid
        left join TUR u on p.id = any(u.jks)
        group by p.id) p
    join TUR u on u.id = p.uid
```

I want to do some where filter on TMB table before left join, so I think can speed up left join.

I think (select * from TMB) is a subquery equal as TMB. I can not understand why this error message. anyone can tell me detail?

Comment: Read the error message it is telling you what you need to know.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I know what, by dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that without the subquery, PostgreSQL can deduce that `id` is the primary key of `tmb`, so you need not add all columns of `tmb` to the `GROUP BY` clause. With the subquery, PostgreSQL cannot make that deduction, so you have to add all columns.

Comment: @Albe thanks :D. But, tmb has many column fields, I dont want to add all column into `group by`. Also, I want subquery with `p.id` as primary key to speed up outer sql. How can I do? Is there any way to make this sql code more simple and faster? Thanks again.

Comment: @Albe Also, I want to know `why subquery without p.id as primary key`. If this ture, are subquery is bad performance for use?

Comment: If you want to know why: because that's how the code was written. The optimizer tries to be smart, but not too smart, so that it can still be fast. You will have to add all the columns that you need to the `GROUP BY` clause. Here is the key, as you already guess: don't use `*`, but only those columns that you really need. There is nothing bad in a subquery as such, don't worry.

Comment: @Albe Thanks, your kindly answer give me great help. I'm a new user to postgres, thanks again :D